# Spring Security, Spring MVC and Login Sessions

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have my Spring MVC & Spring Security up and running as suggested by Spring's own reference application "petclinic". Everything's fine except that the login does not persist a browser restart.

What has to be considered to make sure a logged in user does not need to relogin after browser restart?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a browser restart, user sessions aren't maintained. So, you login informations doesn't survive a browser restart because they are stored in session.

To set up a login that survives browser restarts, you need to implement a cookie based authentication, also known as "Remember me" in Spring security.

To set up "Remember me" using Spring security, I suggest you [the following article](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=213).
You can also check out [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, just what I have been looking for.

Comment: BTW, I guess the article you are referring to is http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=213

Comment: Yes, 1 char was lost during copy/paste operations... Updated to correct the link, thanks.